# how to double the content of a file

Tags: notepad++

I've an ASCII file contains a two dimensional array of size 360X720, with all 1's & 0's.
I want to double the size of that array horizontally like 720X720. By repeating the same content. How can I do that from notepad or notepad++? Suggest me if there is any macro in the notepad++.

Comment: It depends on how your array is presented in the file.

Comment: @BoltClock: it's `all 1's & 0's`

Comment: @sehe: I suppose a simple find `^(.*)$` and replace with `\1\1` would do it in that case!

Comment: @BoltClock: make that an answer? I assume it would do it in most other cases as well (perhaps replacing with `\1,\1` or minor variations)

Answer (score 1):

Rectangular selection FTW

- rectangularly select your array (holding alt key)
- copy
- move caret at the end of first line
- paste

Comment: just found this out myself :) http://kudithipudi.org/2008/07/08/howto-select-column-in-notepad/ (note that this has been a feature of Visual Studio a long time)

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm not sure you can.

In gvim ([download](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)):

you'd do:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

1. `gg` (go to first line)
2. `C-q` -- start visual block select mode (assumes `behave mswin`; if you have `behave xterm` (default except on windows) use <kbd>C-v</kbd> instead)
3. `$` extend block selection to end of line
4. `G` extend block selection to last line (if you have empty trailing lines, move cursor back up or do <kbd>}</kbd>k$ instead)
5. `y` - yank selection into default register
6. `P` - paste (*put*) yanked selection *before* cursor **in blockwise mode**

All done